# XSLT - create new elements and values

Tags: xslt

This is the original input file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<SSC>
    <Payload>
        <Item>
            <Characteristics>
                <CharacteristicCode>NRF COLOR</CharacteristicCode>
                <AlphaValues>
                    <CharacteristicCode>NRF COLOR</CharacteristicCode>
                    <DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>000</DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>
                </AlphaValues>
            </Characteristics>
            <Characteristics>
                <CharacteristicCode>SIZE</CharacteristicCode>
                <AlphaValues>
                    <CharacteristicCode>SIZE</CharacteristicCode>
                    <DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>10</DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>
                </AlphaValues>
                <AlphaValues>
                    <CharacteristicCode>SIZE</CharacteristicCode>
                    <DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>11</DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>
                </AlphaValues>
                <AlphaValues>
                    <CharacteristicCode>SIZE</CharacteristicCode>
                    <DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>12</DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>
                </AlphaValues>
            </Characteristics>
            <Characteristics>
                <CharacteristicCode>UPC</CharacteristicCode>
                <AlphaValues>
                    <CharacteristicCode>UPC</CharacteristicCode>
                    <DiscreteValueAlphanumeric></DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>
                </AlphaValues>
            </Characteristics>
        </Item>
    </Payload>
</SSC>
```

Based on the Characteristic Code "SIZE", I need to append the file with an additional Characteristic element called "UPC". For each Size, a UPC code will be created. So the end result would be like this

```
<Characteristics>
    <CharacteristicCode>UPC</CharacteristicCode>
    <AlphaValues>
        <CharacteristicCode>UPC</CharacteristicCode>
        <DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>UPC-10</DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>
    </AlphaValues>
    <AlphaValues>
        <CharacteristicCode>UPC</CharacteristicCode>
        <DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>UPC-11</DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>
    </AlphaValues>
    <AlphaValues>
        <CharacteristicCode>UPC</CharacteristicCode>
        <DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>UPC-12</DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>
    </AlphaValues>
</Characteristics>
```

Here's my code so far. I was not able to concatenate 'UPC' in the field due to the problem with the loop

```
    <xsl:template match="/SSC/Payload/Item/Characteristics/AlphaValues[CharacteristicCode='UPC']">
        <xsl:for-each select = "/SSC/Payload/Item/Characteristics/AlphaValues[CharacteristicCode='SIZE']/DiscreteValueAlphanumeric">
            <AlphaValues>
                <CharacteristicCode>UPC</CharacteristicCode>
                <DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>
                    <xsl:value-of select = "/SSC/Payload/Item/Characteristics/AlphaValues[CharacteristicCode='SIZE']/DiscreteValueAlphanumeric"/>
                </DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>
            </AlphaValues>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

But this is what i ended up with. All the values were concatenated in each loop

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SSC>
   <Payload>
      <Item>
         <Characteristics>
            <CharacteristicCode>NRF COLOR</CharacteristicCode>
            <AlphaValues>
               <CharacteristicCode>NRF COLOR</CharacteristicCode>
               <DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>000</DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>
            </AlphaValues>
         </Characteristics>
         <Characteristics>
            <CharacteristicCode>SIZE</CharacteristicCode>
            <AlphaValues>
               <CharacteristicCode>SIZE</CharacteristicCode>
               <DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>10</DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>
            </AlphaValues>
            <AlphaValues>
               <CharacteristicCode>SIZE</CharacteristicCode>
               <DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>11</DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>
            </AlphaValues>
            <AlphaValues>
               <CharacteristicCode>SIZE</CharacteristicCode>
               <DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>12</DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>
            </AlphaValues>
         </Characteristics>
         <Characteristics>
            <CharacteristicCode>UPC</CharacteristicCode>
            <AlphaValues>
               <CharacteristicCode>UPC</CharacteristicCode>
               <DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>10 11 12</DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>
            </AlphaValues>
            <AlphaValues>
               <CharacteristicCode>UPC</CharacteristicCode>
               <DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>10 11 12</DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>
            </AlphaValues>
            <AlphaValues>
               <CharacteristicCode>UPC</CharacteristicCode>
               <DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>10 11 12</DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>
            </AlphaValues>
         </Characteristics>
      </Item>
   </Payload>
</SSC>
```

Sorry I was trying to simplify my problem previously and didn't realize that it was causing even more problem. 
Really appreciate any suggestion!

Comment: Welcome to SO. What did you try and what is the problem ? Please give a [mcve] of your actual programming problem. See [ask]

Comment: Thanks! So far I was trying with a for-each loop.

Comment: Can you post the code ?

Comment: I have just edited the post. Thanks!

Comment: I am not a specialist of XSLT who is able to answer your question but with the current formatting it will be easier for such a specialist to help you

Comment: thanks! My apology. This is my first post :)

Comment: This doesn't add up. Your template matches `/SSC/Payload/Item/Characteristics/AlphaValues` but your input shows no `SSC` or `Payload` or `Item ` elements   - in fact, it has no root element, so it''s not XML. And the select expressions will not select anything, because `Characteristics` is not the root element - so a path that starts with `/Characteristics` is meaningless. Please post a **reproducible** example - see: [mcve].

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k. I was trying to simplify the question (which made it even more confusing), sorry for that. I edited the question above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/SSC">
    <Characteristics>
        <CharacteristicCode>UPC</CharacteristicCode>
        <xsl:for-each select="Payload/Item/Characteristics[CharacteristicCode='SIZE']/AlphaValues">
            <AlphaValues>
                <CharacteristicCode>UPC</CharacteristicCode>
                <DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>
                    <xsl:text>UPC-</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="DiscreteValueAlphanumeric"/>
                </DiscreteValueAlphanumeric>
            </AlphaValues>
        </xsl:for-each>
   </Characteristics>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note the *relative* path used from within `xsl:for-each`.

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPJ8LUV